# stuck in WebRTC ICE checking state

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to get a browser client to connect with my C++ linux application using WebRTC. So my environment is not the typical triangle WebRTC where 2 browsers setup a WebRTC call thru a server.  Instead, the browser client side is typical, but my application is acting as the server and the remote client, so it does the signalling and also streams the SRTP media using gstreamer.

I am successful up to a point. I have successfully exchanged the ice candidates and the offer/answer SDP exchange is also successful. The browser ICE connection state successfully goes to "checking" and at that point I am stuck.

Question: Is the server or remote browser involved in the ice checking operations?  That is, does the browser do the ICE checking with the STUN server or with the actual candidate address from the remote end.  That would then imply that my C++ application has to be involved in that checking process.

Thanks,
-Andres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your server needs to respond to STUN binding requests at least which are sent as part of ICE.

If your server always has a public IP, using ice-lite (see [RFC 5245](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245#section-2.7)) will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: thanks for your help. I am playing around with the ice-lite options and studying the RFCs