# WebRTC android hangs after answer. No ICE candidates received

Tags: android, webrtc, stun, turn, ice

I'm using the latest version of WebRTC Android that's available via Gradle. I have two physical android phones and am trying to use WebRTC to communicate between them.

I have tried using [lists of public STUN servers](https://gist.github.com/yetithefoot/7592580) as well as setting up STUN/TURN with [`xirsys`](https://xirsys.com/) and also building and running [`coTurn`](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) (all without any progress).

I could only find one other post about this issue: "[stuck in WebRTC ICE checking state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37504461/4571656)" but the solution there didn't help my problem.

I can see that the offer and answer are both being sent and received, but then nothing happens. The devices appear to be stuck in the CHECKING state for the ICE candidates. Neither device ever sends their ICE candidates.

I tried reading through the documentation but it's nigh impossible to find any troubleshooting help for Android.

Comment: did you try Google STUN servers? the same issue?

Comment: Same issue. I found a github repo that works (communication occurs between android and chrome browser) so I'm going to dissect that and try and see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I switched from using WebRTC to using libjingle (version: 11139@aar) and with very minor tweaks the same code works fine. The package names are all the same (`org.webrtc`) but this one actually seems to work. I don't know why.